# Markov Chain: Find the most probable path from point A to point B

Tags: python, python-3.7, markov-chains

I have a transition matrix using dictionary

```py
{'hex1': {'hex2': 1.0},
 'hex2': {'hex4': 0.4, 'hex7': 0.2, 'hex6': 0.2, 'hex1': 0.2},
 'hex4': {'hex3': 1.0},
 'hex3': {'hex6': 0.3333333333333333, 'hex2': 0.6666666666666666},
 'hex6': {'hex1': 0.3333333333333333,
  'hex4': 0.3333333333333333,
  'hex5': 0.3333333333333333},
 'hex7': {'hex6': 1.0},
 'hex5': {'hex3': 1.0}}
```

which shows the probability of going from a certain hex to another hex (e.g. `hex1` has probability 1 going to `hex2`, `hex2` has probability 0.4 going to `hex4`).

Taking the starting and endpoint, I want to find the path that has the highest probability.

The structure of the code will look like

```py
def find_most_probable_path(start_hex, end_hex, max_path):
    path = compute for maximum probability path from start_hex to end_hex
    return path
```

where max_path is the maximum hexes to traverse. If there is no path within the max_path, return empty/null. Also, drop the path if goes back to the starting hex before reaching the ending hex.

Example would be

```py
find_most_probable_path(hex2, hex3, 5)
>> "hex2,hex4,hex3"
```

The output can be a list of hexes or just concatenated strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I developed an algorithm but I have no idea about its efficiency but it works well.

```
table={'hex1': {'hex2': 1.0},
 'hex2': {'hex4': 0.4, 'hex7': 0.2, 'hex6': 0.2, 'hex1': 0.2},
 'hex4': {'hex3': 1.0},
 'hex3': {'hex6': 0.3333333333333333, 'hex2': 0.6666666666666666},
 'hex6': {'hex1': 0.3333333333333333,
  'hex4': 0.3333333333333333,
  'hex5': 0.3333333333333333},
 'hex7': {'hex6': 1.0},
 'hex5': {'hex3': 1.0}}

def find_most_probable_path(start_hex, end_hex, max_path=0):
    assigned=[start_hex]
    foundTrue=False
    prob=[{"nodes":[start_hex],"prob":1,"length":1}]
    if max_path==0:
        status=False
    else:
        status=True
    while status==True:
        chn=[]
        status=False
        for i in prob:
            if i["length"]<max_path:
                lastElement=i["nodes"][-1]
                for j in table[lastElement]:
                    if j not in assigned:
                        temp=i.copy()
                        js=temp["nodes"].copy()
                        js.append(j)
                        temp["nodes"]=js
                        temp["prob"]=temp["prob"]*table[lastElement][j]
                        temp["length"]+=1
                        #print(temp)
                        chn.append(temp)
                        status=True
        maxv=0
        for i in chn:
            if i["prob"]>=maxv:
                maxv=i["prob"]
                added=i
        if added["nodes"][-1]==end_hex:
            foundTrue=True
            status=False
        assigned.append(added["nodes"][-1])
        prob.append(added)
    if foundTrue==True:
        return prob[-1]["nodes"]
    else:
        return None


print(find_most_probable_path("hex2", "hex3",5))
```

The output will be:

```
['hex2', 'hex4', 'hex3']
```

If you want to see probability of path, you can change the part:

```
if foundTrue==True:
    return prob[-1]["nodes"]
```

to:

```
if foundTrue==True:
    return prob[-1]
```

Then the program give output like that:

```
{'nodes': ['hex2', 'hex4', 'hex3'], 'prob': 0.4, 'length': 3}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. For clarification, this is a brute force method to find the most likely path by iterating all the possible combinations of paths, correct?

Comment: Im insired from shortest path and created some algorithm like that. That does not check all possible paths, the main idea is that find the most possible node which is adjasent to the node list.

Comment: So in essence, you are treating the problem as graph, similar to Dijkstra mentioned in another answer?

Comment: Exactly, its very similar to dijkstra algorithm, but not as shortest path, as the most probable path.

Answer (score 3):

You can treat your Markov Chain as a directed weighted graph, and use the probabilities as graph edges weights.

From this point, you can use the Dijkstra algorithm for a shortest path from two points on a weighted graph.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm